# weights of projections and norms of operators in a von Neumann algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be an atomless von Neumann algebra equipped with a (semifinite faithful normal) weight $w$. Let $x\in M$ and let $\varepsilon>0$.
Can we find a constant $\delta>0$ such that whenever a projection $p\in M$ satisfies $w(p)<\delta$, then $\|p^\perp xp^\perp \|_\infty \ge \|x\|_\infty -\varepsilon$?

I know how to prove the type I and type II case but I am not sure about the general type III case. Probably, it is a known result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this indeed holds in general. The main point is to prove the following: if $p_n$ is a sequence of projections in $M$ such that $w(p_n) \to 0$, then $p_n \to 0$ strongly.

To prove this, one needs a bit of modular theory. One defines $\mathcal{N}_w = \{x \in M \mid w(x^*x) < +\infty\}$ and one denotes by $H$ the Hilbert space completion of $\mathcal{N}_w$ with the canonical injective linear map $\Lambda_w : \mathcal{N}_w \to H$ satisfying $\langle \Lambda_w(x) ,\Lambda_w(y) \rangle = w(y^*x)$. One represents $M$ on $H$ by left multiplication: $x \Lambda_w(y) = \Lambda_w(xy)$. One denotes by $J_w$ the anti-unitary conjugation on $H$, and by $(\sigma_t^w)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ the modular automorphism group. The key equality is the following: if $a \in \mathcal{N}_w$ and $a$ belongs to the domain of the analytic continuation $\sigma_{i/2}^w$, then $J_w \sigma^w_{i/2}(a)^* J_w \Lambda_w(x) = x \Lambda_w(a)$ for all $x \in \mathcal{N}_w$.

If now $w(p_n) \to 0$, also $\Lambda_w(p_n) \to 0$ in $H$ and we find that $p_n \Lambda_w(a) \to 0$ in $H$ for all $a$ as above. Since the set of these $\Lambda_w(a)$ is dense in $H$, it follows that $p_n \to 0$ strongly.

Then also $p_n^\perp \to 1$ strongly, from which it follows that $\|p_n^\perp x p_n^\perp\|_\infty \to \|x\|_\infty$ for all $x \in M$.

Comment: Thank you very much! BTW, are there any references for such a result? or just folklore?

Comment: The essence can almost surely be found in one of the volumes of Takesaki's "Theory of Operator Algebras", but I did not look for a precise reference.

Comment: Thank you so much!